# Excel VBA to sum cells backwards based on a variable number of cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a code that will add the cell in the same row but 3 columns backwards, and then every cell 4 columns backwards a certain amount of times. I want to inputbox a number and have it add 3 columns back and then 4 columns back as many times as I said in the input box.

For example, if I have range("AS2") selected, run the macro, and input 4 into the input box, the formula printed in AS2 would be "=AP2+AL2+AH2+AD2".  If I entered 6 into the inputbox, the formula in AS2 would be "=AP2+AL2+AH2+AD2+Z2+V2"

what i'm working on so far looks like this:

```
I2 = Selection.Column
I3 = 3 'I3 will be changed to inputbox.  practicing adding 2 rows backwards 3 times for now

rngS = Replace(Cells(2, (I2 - 2)).Address, "$", "")
FormulaS = "=" & rngS

For I = 2 To I3

rngS = Replace(Cells(2, I2 - (2 * I)).Address, "$", "")
FormulaS = FormulaS & "+" & rngS

Next I

Cells(2, I2).Value = FormulaS
```

Thank you,

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward. What have you attempted already?

Comment: @BigBen

What i'm working on looks like this so far:
[code]I2 = Selection.Column
I3 = 3 'I3 will be changed to inputbox after code is perfected.  practicing adding 4 rows backwards 3 times for now

rngS = Replace(Cells(2, I2 - 4).Address, "$", "")
Debug.Print rngS

For I = 1 To I3

FormulaS = rngS & "+" &
rngS = Replace(Cells(2, I2 - (4 * I)).Address, "$", "")
Next I [code]


Added code to original post since i cannot figure out how to make the comment look presentable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the column number for the selected cell with `Selection.Column`. Now, you can simply subtract the input value from the obtained column number and get the column number of the next cell. Now, you need to get the address of the cell with `Cells(Selection.Row, obtainedColumnNumber).Address` (add `False, False` if you need relative references). Then, just join the obtained addresses with plus sign and add equal sign at the beginning.